# How to hide options in select list Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have `ng-repeat`:

```
<option ng-repeat="year in data.dateList.year" ng-hide="year.id < limit" value="{{year.id}}" ng-selected="year.id == 0">
   {{year.value}}
</option>
```

And `$scope.limit = 1991;`

I try to hide options by condition:

```
ng-hide="year.id < limit"
```

It does not work

Comment: you can not hide `<option>` cross browser. IE for example does not support it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this by using filter:show

```
ng-repeat="year in data.dateList.year | filter:show"
```

JS

```
$scope.show=function(year){
  return year.id > $scope.limit
}
```

if you want to get index

Try like this

```
$scope.show = function(year) {
    console.log(getIndex($scope.data.dateList.year, year))
    return year.id > $scope.limit
}

function getIndex(dataList, data) {
    var index = -1;
    dataList.some(function(item, i) {
        if (JSON.stringify(item) == JSON.stringify(data)) {
            index = i;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return index;
}
```

Comment: you don't need to. it'll send instance of data.dateList.year into show from filter

Comment: I need something like as: `filter:show:$index"`  AJ: `$scope.show=function(year, index){..}` Is it correct?

Comment: why need index where your have year object ?? you can find index using object from their list.

Comment: I have model in `ng-repeat` with `$index` like as `modal[$index]` And I need curret $index to function `show()` that to compare two models with `$index` current

Comment: @Ahmed try this: `filter:show($index)` and `$scope.show = function (index) { return function (year) { .. }; };`

Comment: Thanks, but if two params? $index and year?

Comment: don't use $index in filters , it won't be index of original array

Comment: $index it for ng-repeat .. ng-options don't have $index like ng-repeat